# in java how do i design an api to be both generic, simple, readable

Tags: java, api, oop

My example is this I want my user to call

```
findCustomers(...)
```

now my question is about the argument to this method.
I have a

```
Customer.java
```

object and I would like the user to be able to use the library to search by customer name, and customer id.

now i would not want to create multiple methods

```
findCustomerById(String id)
findCustomerByName(String name)
findAllCustomers()
```

Instead what I thought of doing is this a generic findCustomer

```
/** if you pass only custoer.name and rest of fields are null will search by name,
if you pass a null custoer object will return all customers, if you pass both custoer id and his name will search by both fields). **/
findCustomer(Customer customer)
```

Now I have a generic single method for api but i don't like that i pass nulls in an object, i don't like nulls.

anyone has a clear cut best practice for such an api?

thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

how about something like a fluid api for queries:

```
List<Customer> matches = find(new CustomerQuery().withName("john(.*)").withId(42));
```

Comment: +1 for using a new type CustomerQuery instead of Customer

Comment: now that i look at this some more you could even build a query factory to avoid that awkward constructor call:
QueryFactory.customer().withName("john(.*)").olderThan(10)
QueryFactory.customer() would be a static factory method tahts returns CustomerQueries. you could then reuse the same query factory for any other entity queries you might have

Answer (score 3):

What you are trying to build is called [*Query By Example*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_by_Example). It is OK, but it has limitations: your `Customer` class is re-purposed for being a query parameter, rendering some of its code useless or counterproductive. For example, if you add a validation requiring the name to contain only letters, you would not be able to query for names with wildcards.

One approach to address this is to provide a query builder class designed specifically to handle query parameters. The query object itself could wrap a `Map<String,Object>` of parameter bindings passed by the user, letting your query API take it apart and pass the corresponding data to a query of the underlying data store.

```
QueryObject<Customer> qObj = new QueryObject(Customer.class);
qObj.setParameter("FirstName", "Joe");
qObj.setParameter("LastName", "S*");
qObj.setParameter("ID", 123);
List<Customer> cust = findCustomers(qObj);
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of passing a Customer object which I assume has many other methods you could have

```
findCustomer(String id, String name); // id or name can be null.
```

or a CustomerSearch object which can have either of these or possibly multiple ids and names.

Comment: i vote for CustomerSearch idea that is the most extensible one.

Comment: this is API! if i add a new field to Customer.java like whatevernew field i will need to change the signature of this method !! and this is api! in case i would find myself in the need to also do a find by this new field!

Comment: If you developing an API is best to not add functionality you may want to remove later, it is easier to add it than to remove it.